# Windows Azure Enterprise Account

Tags: azure

What is the difference between Windows Azure Enterprise account and normal Azure account

Enterprise account:- https://ea.windowsazure.com/

Azure:- http://www.windowsazure.com

Does interface for Subscription management and Administrator management is different in both of them?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with an Azure EA sales rep last week and the only difference currently (Feb 2015) is in pricing. The prices posted on the Azure site are their "rack rates". To get EA pricing, which they said would be 5%-20% cheaper, you need to agree up front to spend at least $25k for the year.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the price concessions that Microsoft makes for you having signed up for an Enterprise Agreement (assuming a $25,000 USD commitment), the administrative interface is slightly different.

In a typical Azure subscription, you have just that...a single Subscription. With an Enterprise Agreement, you can create numerous Accounts and within each Account you may create numerous Subscriptions. This is sometimes used for organizations that wish to use a chargeback model and issue an Account or Subscription for accounting purposes (e.g. Marketing, IT, Operations). As an alternative, you could use the Subscriptions as a level of isolation (e.g. DEV, TEST, PROD).

In summary, the Azure services available for consumption are the same, but the billing setup, pricing, usage reporting, and isolation offer you a greater level of management oversight.